# margin:0 auto IE6 problem

Tags: c#, css

Can someone please tell me ehy in IE 6 div is not in center. I use margin: 0 auto; Problem is only in IE6!

```
HTML

<div id="center">
    <div id="top_menu">
        <a href="/Default.aspx">Domov</a> 
        · <a href="/EnterSite.aspx">Vpišite stran</a> 
        · <a href="/About.aspx">O nas</a> 
        · <a href="/Help.aspx">Pomoč pri iskanju</a> 
        · <a href="/Marketing.aspx">Oglaševanje</a> 
        · <a href="/Info.aspx">Splošni pogoji in pravila</a>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.viamura.si"><img src="/images/viamura_logo.png" width="294" height="95" border="0" alt="viamura" /></a>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnWeb" runat="server" CssClass="web_selected" 
                    onclick="btnWeb_Click">Web</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnMap" runat="server" CssClass="map" 
                    onclick="btnMap_Click">Zemljevidi</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnWeather" runat="server" CssClass="weather" 
                    onclick="btnWeather_Click">Vreme</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnImages" runat="server" CssClass="images" 
                    onclick="btnImages_Click">Slike</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="btnConverter" runat="server" CssClass="converter" 
                    onclick="btnConverter_Click">Converter</asp:LinkButton></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#center {
width:520px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#tabs {
width:400px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#tabs ul li a.web,#tabs ul li a.map,#tabs ul li a.weather,#tabs ul li a.images,#tabs ul li a.converter,#tabs ul li a.web_selected,#tabs ul li a.map_selected,#tabs ul li a.weather_selected,#tabs ul li a.images_selected,#tabs ul li a.converter_selected {
background-color:#0C0;
float:left;
height:18px;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

#tabs ul {
float:left;
width:459px;
margin:10px 0 0 41px;
}

#tabs ul li {
float:left;
margin:0 2px 0 0;
}

#tabs ul li a.web {
background:url(../images/tab_web.png) no-repeat;
width:46px;
}

#tabs ul li a.map {
background:url(../images/tab_map.png) no-repeat;
width:80px;
}

#tabs ul li a.weather {
background:url(../images/tab_weather.png) no-repeat;
width:58px;
}

#tabs ul li a.images {
background:url(../images/tab_images.png) no-repeat;
width:48px;
}

#tabs ul li a.converter {
background:url(../images/tab_converter.png) no-repeat;
width:78px;
}

#tabs ul li a.web_selected {
background:url(../images/tab_web_selected.png) no-repeat;
width:46px;
}

#tabs ul li a.map_selected {
background:url(../images/tab_map_selected.png) no-repeat;
width:80px;
}

#tabs ul li a.weather_selected {
background:url(../images/tab_weather_selected.png) no-repeat;
width:58px;
}

#tabs ul li a.images_selected {
background:url(../images/tab_images_selected.png) no-repeat;
width:48px;
}

#tabs ul li a.converter_selected {
background:url(../images/tab_converter_selected.png) no-repeat;
width:78px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put

```
text-align: center
```

either in the `body`, or an additional `div` around the `center` div.

```
body
 { text-align: center; }
```

To prevent all child elements from having centered text as well, you'll have to reset the text-align:

```
#center {
 width:520px;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align: left;
 }
```

Comment: i did exactly as you said but is the same. In IE6 #tabs are not in the center

Comment: @senzacionale you need to repeat this for every element you need centered: Give the parent of that element `text-align: center`. IE6 doesn't recognize the `margin: auto` part.

Comment: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/hacks-browser-detection.shtml -> i use html>body for IE and works. Thx